# Http Compression on Binary Data

Tags: http, compression

I am serving binary data through http.
For the time being I use `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Can I use the built in http compression (having the client request data with the header `Accept-Encoding`) to compress the attachment?

Or should I compress the attachment manually?

What is the proper way of serving compressed byte arrays through http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content-disposition` is [merely a header instructing the browser to either render the response, or to offer it as a download to the user](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). It doesn't change any HTTP semantics, and it doesn't change how the response body is transferred or interpreted.

So just use the built-in compression that compresses the response body according to the request header `Accept-encoding`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was using akka-http where `application-octet/stream` is not compressible by default